# 404 routing issue - AWS Linux / Wordpress site

Tags: linux, wordpress, amazon-web-services, .htaccess

We are running a WordPress site on a AWS EC2 Linux instance and have created custom 403 and 404 error files (both html files). The files are located in the root of the website.

The root .htaccess file has been amended to include the following section:

```
# Custom Documents

ErrorDocument 403 /403.html

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

The site uses a theme and within this there is a 404.php file. The problem is that any 404 requests are being routed to this file instead of the 404.html file.

The httpd.conf file has all access set for the root folder var/www/html so there’s nothing in it that I can see that would be blocking the .htaccess file. As a double check I added some 301 redirects into the .htaccess file just to check if they were getting hit and they were working.

Also checked if there were any other .htaccess files which might be overriding the one in , there were some in a plugin but from what I can see they shouldn’t have any impact.

Is there anything else which could be overriding the .htaccess file?

Comment: `ErrorDocument 404` doesn't work in Wordpress. It shows by default `404.php` inside your selected theme. You can put your custom code in that file.

Comment: thanks @anubhava that explains things! - add as an answer if you want a tick..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ErrorDocument 404` doesn't work in Wordpress like regular pages. Wordpress by default shows `404.php` content from inside your selected theme. You can put your custom code in that `404.php` file.

Here is official Wordpress guide for [**Creating an Error 404 Page**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page)